# logical error with figuring out if an input is purely letters in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that takes a word as an input and makes sure it is made of all letters and no other characters. this is what I have so far:

```
for(int i = 0, length = strlen(argv[1]); i < length; i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("success\n");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is if I put in a word with three letters, it prints out the word success three times. I cannot seem to find my way around it, can you help me?

Comment: It would be better to print an error message such as `fprintf(stderr, "%s: non-letter %c in keyword '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1][i], argv[1]);` as well as the usage message `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");` (where we can negotiate about whether to use `%s` and `argv[0]` in the usage message).  Note that error messages should be written to standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `print success` out of the for loop.

```c
for(int i = 0, length = strlen(argv[1]); i < length; i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
printf("success\n");
```

Comment: But that way it will print it even if the word has letters in it!

Comment: @Yasmin — no it won't.  If there's a letter in the word, you'll print the usage message and exit (`return 1;` inside `main()` is essentially equivalent to `exit(1);`).